# Laravel 5.4 version public doesn't remove

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5

I can't remove public from url. And asset function doesn't automatic direct public folder. How can I solve this?
page does not load css files.

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Fizyoterapi Takip</title>
  <!-- Plugins CSS -->
  <link href="{{asset('/Back/css/plugins/plugins.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{asset('/Back/smart-form/smart-templates/css/smart-forms.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{asset('/Back/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    #id{
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Does it mean that the asset url contains '/public/'?

Comment: when I write assets
code output ' <link href="http://fitoloji.website/Back/css/plugins/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet">'  
but does not load css files

Comment: what is your current hostname and can show config/app.php 'asset_url'?

Comment: when i wrote this url (http://fitoloji.website/) ,my site css folder does not load but 
when i wrote this url (http://fitoloji.website/public) ,my site css folder is loading
.I want to work in the first url(http://fitoloji.website/)

Comment: 'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Spor Programı'),

    
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

       'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://fitoloji.website/'),

       'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'locale' => 'en',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',


    'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

    'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),